# unable to convert image to Base64 format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner in javascript and I am using the pokemon api `https://pokeapi.co/` to get pokemon images . After I get an image I try to convert it to base64 format but I get the error

```
pokemon.js:29 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getBase64 is not defined
```

I have looked at other answers here about similar issues with this but I am a beginner and cannot understand well .

My code :

```js
var pokeInfo=[];
var pokepics=[];
var pokemon;

//get a pokemon by id 
async function fetchPokemon(pokemonID){
  
    var response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+pokemonID.toString()+'/');
    var poke = await response.json();
    pokeInfo.push(poke);
}


//get many  pokemon 
async function fetchManyPokemon(count){

    for(var i=1;i<=count;i++){

        await fetchPokemon(count);      
    }
}

//get pokemon image 
async function fetchPokemonImage(pokemonInfo){

    var imageUrl = pokemonInfo.sprites.front_default; //select image 
    var imageResponse = await fetch(imageUrl); //fetch image
    var image = await imageResponse.blob(); // get response image
    //error is here 
    var base64 = await getBase64(image); //convert image to base 64 format 

    pokepics.push(base64);


}


async function fetchPokemonImages(){  //fetch number of pokemon images 

    for(var l =0;l<pokeInfo.length;l++){
    
        await fetchPokemonImage(pokeInfo[l]);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me through this issue .
Thank you in advance .

Comment: There is no `getBase64` function in this scope, there is also no `getBase64` function in the standard JS library. Are you trying to import it from somewhere?

Comment: @ngr900 I am following a tutorial it is written this way exactly link :https://coderdojo.gitbooks.io/advanced-javascript-sushi/content/en/asking_for_data.html

Comment: btw why do you want to get it as base64? You already have an image url - why not just display that?

Comment: Frankly I have no idea what they're doing over there, there is no function like this in JS and they're not showing any imports or its declaration. My guess would be that the person writing this tutorial defined it in their code and then forgot to include it in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no getBase64() in js ,
You should try that way:

```
function toBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
```

Comment: that's weird the tutorial I am following has that method link:https://coderdojo.gitbooks.io/advanced-javascript-sushi/content/en/asking_for_data.html

Comment: that is really weird , unless we missed anything in there